# Momentum in quantum harmonic oscillator with step up and step down operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

I'm hitting a wall in my understanding of the momentum operator in a quantum harmonic oscillator. I've showed that $p = (a^\dagger - a)\sqrt{\frac{m w \hbar}{2}}i$ where $a^\dagger$ and $a$ are the step up and step down operators, and $i$ is the imaginary number.

> I'm trying to calculate $<m|p|n>$ using this momentum operator, where |m> and |n> are just different states of the system.

My work so far is:

$\begin{align}
<m|p|n> &= <m|(a^\dagger - a)\sqrt{\frac{m w \hbar}{2}}i|n> \\
&=<m|a^\dagger\sqrt{\frac{m w \hbar}{2}}i|n> - <m|a\sqrt{\frac{m w \hbar}{2}}i|n> \\
&=\sqrt{\frac{m w \hbar}{2}}i (<m|a^\dagger|n> - <m|a|n>)
\end{align}$

And this is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure what I can do from here.

Comment: What happens if $m = n \pm 1$? What happens otherwise?

Comment: I believe if $ m = n \pm 1$, then the inner product is 1 and 0 otherwise since they are othonormal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ladder operators satisfy:

$\bf{a^{\dagger}}$$|n>=\sqrt{n+1}|n+1>$

$\bf{a}$$|n>=\sqrt{n}|n-1>$

Taking into account $<n|m>=\delta_{n,m}$ , you get the answer.